# How to make indicators like in iPhone mail that tell you how many email are in your individual inbox?

Tags: ios, email, uitableview

Wondering if anyone knows how to implement the grey circles with a number indicating how many emails are in your various inboxes in iPhone mail?

Is there an existing API to use these in tableView cells? If so what is it called?

I'm considering subclassing UIView to make something similar but if it's already out there I'll use what's available.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no easy way to do this. You have to use custom cells for the purpose. Apple's table view programming guide demonstrates how customizing can be done.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW18